# failed access to javascript objects

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have json data like this image, which I got from PHP.
[image]

and I want to access all data from json.
for my current case, I want to match existing data with data from Json.

[image]

but i got a little error. all of my data is not same with Json data.
Though there must be some data that is suitable.

[image]

this my code

```
const dataArr = <?= $ar; ?>;
console.log(dataArr); //image 1
var mySVG = document.getElementById("alphasvg");
var svgDoc;
mySVG.addEventListener("load",function() {

    svgDoc = mySVG.contentDocument.documentElement;
    var xd = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("rect");

        for(i=0;i<xd.length;i++){
            let get_a = xd[i].getAttribute('id');
            for(x = 1; x<= 30; x++){
                for(y=0; y<=4; y++){
                    if(get_a == 'rect' + x + '_child' + y){
                        //console.log(get_a); //img2
                        if(dataArr[(x-1)*y].idval.includes(get_a) == true){
                            console.log('yes u good');
                        } else {
                            console.log('error');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, false);
```

can somone help me?

edit : resut of `console.log(get_a,dataArr[(x-1)*y]);` 
[image]
my data is not matching.

Comment: I assume the first screenshot is the output of `console.log(dataArr);` is it? If so, does `get_a` match the index of the array `dataArr[(x-1)*y]` you're trying to look for a match? I recommend adding a `console.log(get_a,dataArr[(x-1)*y]);` to see if it's the correct row.

Comment: As you posted another screenshot that clearly shows the data doesn't match, I'm still unsure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to find the element inside dataArr that matches the id of an html element returned by `var xd = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("rect");`?

Comment: yes that's right, my current goal is only to match the ID from rect and my db, so that later I can throw the data into the modals with the onclick feature. @obscure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to search the objects inside the array for a particular occurence of a key - **idval** - and it's value you can use a simple for-loop like:

```
for (var a = 0; a < dataArr.length; a++) {
  if (dataArr[a].idval == get_a) {
    console.log("there it is", dataArr[a]);
    break;
  }
}
```

Here's an example:

```js
var dataArr = [{
    id: "test",
    lantai: 1,
    status_asrama: "tersedia",
    idval: "rect_child1"
  },
  {
    id: "anothertest",
    lantai: 2,
    status_asrama: "tersedia",
    idval: "rect_child2"
  }, {
    id: "finaltest",
    lantai: 3,
    status_asrama: "tersedia",
    idval: "rect_child3"
  }
];

let get_a = "rect_child2";

for (var a = 0; a < dataArr.length; a++) {
  if (dataArr[a].idval == get_a) {
    console.log("there it is", dataArr[a]);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: No problem @Cinta - glad I could help!